# Cannot add application insights bare api to java web application

Tags: java, eclipse, azure, azure-application-insights

I added all the jar files of application insight sdk for java in java web project and included the code for sending custom telemetry in servlet but when i try to run the servlet it shows classnotfound error for TelemetryConfiguration and TelemetryClient.

Comment: How did you add all the jar files of application insight sdk? Via the pom.xml of Maven Project or add them into the path `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib`or add thru configure the `Java Build Path`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my experience, I think you can try to check the jar files of Application Insight SDK for Java whether be added the `Libraries` of `Java Build Path`, please right click the prject name and select the `Properties` in the menu.

If using Maven project, you can see the jar files in the `Maven Dependencies`.

If using the normal `Dynamic Web Project`, you can see them in the `Web App Libraries` or a `User Library` with custom name.

Then you need to try to manually build the project, and run the servlet again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you added only the web library without the core library, which contains the TelemetryClient class.

You can read the [Application Insights Java SDK article](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/insights/app-insights-java) which describes in details how to add the Java SDK to your web project, whether you're using Maven or Gradle as your build system, or manually downloading and referencing the libraries.